# multiple if then else statement with arithmetic

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a medical report that I need to alter the value of each appointment code. 
If  {Schedule.Activity} = "123"
then give it a value of 2, 
if  {Schedule.Activity} = "124"
then    1 
else 1

The list is quite long of specific codes and what value they need to be for counting. Currently the report is counting all appointments as just 1. 
I could do individual formulas but can anyone help with just one? 
at the end of the report, they will all need to be summed as well. 
I'm still new to CR so please have simple explanations and all the right syntax!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Select {Schedule.Activity}   

   Case "123" : 1

   Case "124" : 2

   Case "125" : 3 

   ///add as many Cases as you like

   Default : 0 ;
```